# Upgrade path for QFX 13.2 to 21.4

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-ex, data-center, documentation, os-upgrade-procedure

I have a Qfx5100-48s-6q box running a software version 13.2X51-D38 that needs to be upgraded to a new version – “jinstall-host-qfx-5-21.4R3-S5.17-signed”.

Any advise us on the upgrade path for this please.